# Gearing a glitchy, static-y sound coming out of the speaker

Tags: sound

I recently upgraded my hardware at the same time I upgrade from 12.04 to 13.04 but I don't think it comes from the 13.04 update itself.

I keep hearing a glitchy, static-y sound coming out of the speaker connected directly to the motherboard (no audio card). It seems the sound gets worst when I move the mouse, scroll pages or the computer seems to be doing work (ie. refreshing a web page).

This doesn't stop with muting the volume in ubuntu, I have to close the speakers to make it stop.

Comment: Does it happen only with speakers plugged in? Do you hear it in headphones?

Comment: over headphones as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a ground loop.

One of the devices plugged into the same electrical outlet as your computer does not have a proper grounding circuit so it's creating electrical feedback, or your computer is plugged into a non-grounded outlet.

Some outlets are not grounded even though they have three holes on the outlet.

You can get a doohicky called a Ground Loop Eliminator at Radio Shack for about ten bucks that will fix the problem. Or probably on Amazon.